# Calculate difference between dates and output desired result like (Today, Tomorrow, or 20 Days from now)

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm writing a task list tracker with VueJS. Each task has a `Frequency` label (How often it needs to be done), Last completed date label (When the task was completed last) and a `Due Date` label which tells the user when a particular task needs to be done.

The code below is used to update the `Due Date` field by accepting 2 arguments (Last_Completed_Date, Frequency). Based on parameters provided I want the Due Date label to change to one of the following options:

- Today
- Tomorrow
- n Number of days

Is this a good way of writing such a function?

```
console.log(difference("2021-09-09T13:52:56.000Z", "Monthly")) // Date=3 Weeks ago, expected result: 21 Days
console.log(difference("2021-09-23T13:52:56.000Z", "Weekly")) // Date=1 Week ago, expected result: Today
console.log(difference("2021-09-29T13:52:56.000Z", "Weekly")) // Date=1 Day ago, expected result: Tomorrow

difference(data, freq) {
      const today = moment();
      const newData = moment(data);
      if (freq === "Daily") {
        return "Today";
      } else if (freq === "Weekly") {
        if (Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) >= 7) {
          return "Today";
        } else if (
          Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) < 7 &&
          Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) > 1
        ) {
          return Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) + " Days";
        } else if (Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) == 1) {
          return "Tomorrow";
        }
      } else if (freq === "Monthly") {
        if (Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) >= 30) {
          return "Today";
        } else if (
          Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) < 30 &&
          Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) > 1
        ) {
          return Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) + " Days";
        } else if (Math.abs(newData.diff(today, "days")) == 1) {
          return "Tomorrow";
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: "Today", "tomorrow", etc., these depend on the timezone (for example, "in 5 hours" can be today if it's 13:00 in my timezone, but will be tomorrow if it's 23:00). Is it OK to default to UTC here? Also, I'm not sure about your examples, could you double-check?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. The time zone used in the examples come from a server set to ‘en-GB’. So UTC+1